# How to remove toolbars in PhpStorm

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm, toolbar, ide-customization

I try to remove two things in PhpStorm but I can not remove them. Do you know if it is possible?

A friend who works on Mac do not have these bars. And I'm on Windows and looking for some time for settings to remove them.

View the attached picture.

1 - Toolbar
2 - Path Method

[image]

Comment: In the view tab you can experiment with presentation mode and fullscreen (these can be combined), maybe this helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. It's Menu bar and not toolbar. On Mac OS X it is not part of the actual app window but rather part of the desktop itself.

   There does not seem to be an option to hide it by just turning some setting off. I recommend trying one of these modes:

   [image]
2. `File | Settings | Editor |General | Appearance --> Show HTML breadcrums`

   - Yes, this option also controls PHP code
   - You need to close and reopen file to see the changes

   [image]

Answer (score 2):

Just for extra reference...

If you are member of [Laracasts](http://laracasts.com), there's a lesson there called "Be awesome with PhpStorm". I learned lots of good stuff from it, one of them being how to completely remove toolbars, breadcrumbs, status bars, so that your IDE is much cleaner. The author (Jeffrey Way) also talks about useful shortcuts and plugins to make your work more productive.

Also, other things that are taught in that lesson and that I'm glad I've done:

- Increase font size (your eyes you be thankful in the long run)
- Remove tabs (Window > Editor Tabs > Tabs Placement > None)
- Using Full Screen + Distraction Free Mode is amazing!
- <kbd>ALT + 1</kbd> toggles sidebar
- <kbd>ALT + F12</kbd> opens command prompt right into your project directory, so that you can start typing Artisan commands pronto.

I hope these tips will help give people a little more productivity.